# How do I correctly wrap a TEXT and hand it to my Template Mark ###SEARCH_FIELD###

Tags: templates, typo3, typoscript

I am currently getting back into typo3 and I have really big problems with the variable concept, it just doesn't do what it is supposed to. See the first Mark SCROLLUP, everything works fine there, but I don't know to get it working for a more complex part.

```
page.10.marks {

  SCROLLUP = TEXT
  SCROLLUP.value = <a href="#top"><div id="scrollup_button">&nbsp;</div></a>

  temp.suche = TEXT
  temp.suche {
    <input type="hidden" name="tx_indexedsearch[sections]" value="0" />
    <input name="tx_indexedsearch[submit_button]" value="Search" type="hidden" />
    <input name="search" src="images/search_red.png" value="Search" class="searchbox-button" type="image" />
  }

  temp.suche.wrap = <form action="suchergebnisse/" method="post" id="indexedsearch">|</form>

  SEARCH_FIELD < temp.suche


}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are three problems:

1. You need to set the value of a TEXT object under its `value` property (cf. [TypoScript reference](http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/ContentObjects/Text/Index.html)):

   ```
   temp.suche = TEXT
   temp.suche.value = [...]
   ```

   or

   ```
   temp.suche = TEXT
   temp.suche {
       value = [...]
   }
   ```
2. Multiline values have to be placed in parenthesis, not braces:

   ```
   temp.suche.value (
        line 1
        line 2
        ...
   )
   ```
3. The object `temp.suche` should be placed at top level, outside the page.10.marks object:

   ```
   temp.suche = TEXT
   temp.suche.value = [...]

   page.10.marks {
       SEARCH_FIELD < temp.suche
   }
   ```